# How to force rebuild with .NET Core on the Mac

Tags: macos, .net-core

In Eclipse we *"clean"*. In Ant we *"clean"*.

How do we clean or force a rebuild with DotNet Core command on the Mac? Trying to rebuild with the simple build command wont build.

```
   Project library (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
    Project test-library (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
```

```
   No executable found matching command "dotnet-clean"
$ :(
```

Edit: Just a note that `dotnet clean` now is a command.

Comment: Does "rebuild" work?

Comment: That would have been awesome :P

Comment: I take it that that's a "no" then? Oh well

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use:

```
dotnet build --no-incremental
```

As stated in [.NET Core SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#options), `--no-incremental` option:

> Marks the build as unsafe for incremental build. This flag turns off
>   incremental compilation and forces a clean rebuild of the project's
>   dependency graph.

Comment: Ver nice. For the copy pasting mac users: `$ dotnet build --no-incremental`.

Comment: Of course, this answer applies not only to Mac OS. It helped me on Windows machine. Thx.

Comment: Just a note that `dotnet clean` now is a command.